# Better PropertyChanged and PropertyChanging event handling

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I am implementing the observer pattern for our application - currently playing around with the RX Framework.

I currently have an example that looks like this:

```
Observable.FromEventPattern<PropertyChangedEventArgs>(Instance.Address, "PropertyChanged")
    .Where(e => e.EventArgs.PropertyName == "City")
    .ObserveOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool)
    .Subscribe(search => OnNewSearch(search.EventArgs));
```

(I have a similar one for "PropertyChanging")

The EventArgs don't give me much. What I would like is an extension of the EventArgs that would give me the ability to see the previous and new values, as well as the ability to mark the event in the 'changing' listener, such that the change wouldn't actually persist. How can this be done? Thanks.

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/19627)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think that it comes down to how you implement the INotifyPropertyChanging and INotifyPropertyChanged interfaces.

The PropertyChangingEventArgs and PropertyChangedEventArgs classes unfortunately don't provide a before and after value of the property or the ability to cancel the change, but you can derive your own event args classes that do provide that functionality.

First, define the following event args classes.  Notice that these derive from the PropertyChangingEventArgs class and PropertyChangedEventArgs class.  This allows us to pass these objects as arguments to the PropertyChangingEventHandler and PropertyChangedEventHandler delegates.

```
class PropertyChangingCancelEventArgs : PropertyChangingEventArgs
{
    public bool Cancel { get; set; }

    public PropertyChangingCancelEventArgs(string propertyName)
        : base(propertyName)
    {
    }
}

class PropertyChangingCancelEventArgs<T> : PropertyChangingCancelEventArgs
{
    public T OriginalValue { get; private set; }

    public T NewValue { get; private set; }

    public PropertyChangingCancelEventArgs(string propertyName, T originalValue, T newValue)
        : base(propertyName)
    {
        this.OriginalValue = originalValue;
        this.NewValue = newValue;
    }
}

class PropertyChangedEventArgs<T> : PropertyChangedEventArgs
{
    public T PreviousValue { get; private set; }

    public T CurrentValue { get; private set; }

    public PropertyChangedEventArgs(string propertyName, T previousValue, T currentValue)
        : base(propertyName)
    {
        this.PreviousValue = previousValue;
        this.CurrentValue = currentValue;
    }
}
```

Next, you would need to use these classes in your implementation of the INotifyPropertyChanging and INotifyPropertyChanged interfaces.  An example of an implementation is the following:

```
class Example : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected bool OnPropertyChanging<T>(string propertyName, T originalValue, T newValue)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanging;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            var args = new PropertyChangingCancelEventArgs<T>(propertyName, originalValue, newValue);
            handler(this, args);
            return !args.Cancel;
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged<T>(string propertyName, T previousValue, T currentValue)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs<T>(propertyName, previousValue, currentValue));
    }

    int _ExampleValue;

    public int ExampleValue
    {
        get { return _ExampleValue; }
        set
        {
            if (_ExampleValue != value)
            {
                if (this.OnPropertyChanging("ExampleValue", _ExampleValue, value))
                {
                    var previousValue = _ExampleValue;
                    _ExampleValue = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("ExampleValue", previousValue, value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note, your event handlers for the PropertyChanging and PropertyChanged events will still need to take the original PropertyChangingEventArgs class and PropertyChangedEventArgs class as parameters, rather than a more specific version.  However, you will be able to cast the event args objects to your more specific types in order to access the new properties.

Below is an example of event handlers for these events:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var exampleObject = new Example();

        exampleObject.PropertyChanging += new PropertyChangingEventHandler(exampleObject_PropertyChanging);
        exampleObject.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(exampleObject_PropertyChanged);

        exampleObject.ExampleValue = 123;
        exampleObject.ExampleValue = 100;
    }

    static void exampleObject_PropertyChanging(object sender, PropertyChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "ExampleValue")
        {
            int originalValue = ((PropertyChangingCancelEventArgs<int>)e).OriginalValue;
            int newValue = ((PropertyChangingCancelEventArgs<int>)e).NewValue;

            // do not allow the property to be changed if the new value is less than the original value
            if(newValue < originalValue)
                ((PropertyChangingCancelEventArgs)e).Cancel = true;
        }

    }

    static void exampleObject_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "ExampleValue")
        {
            int previousValue = ((PropertyChangedEventArgs<int>)e).PreviousValue;
            int currentValue = ((PropertyChangedEventArgs<int>)e).CurrentValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to implement this using a DynamicProxy, to avoid all of that code in the setter methods?

Comment: @user981225 - I'm not familiar with DynamicProxy (such as in [Castle](http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html)?), but I guess you mean taking an AOP or policy injection approach.  I agree with your line of thinking and I would definitely look for some mechanism (AOP, policy injection, or otherwise) to consolidate that property setter code so that you don't have lots of redundant code. I don't have any particular mechanism to recommend offhand, though.

Comment: Thank you very much for all of your help, it is appreciated. If I can find an elegant Proxy solution I will post it here.

Comment: This is useful information, but I am ... as usual ... bothered by the fact that subscribers to the Events must cast the Property specific Changed and Changing events to the Custom Arguments Type in order to access the internal fields. I think there should be a way to do this that doesn't require the cast, but I can't find it.

Comment: @Dr.Wily'sApprentice how can I access that `.PropertyChanging +=` member on `Example`? Where does that come from?

Comment: @Thomas that event is defined by your own code, as in my `Example` class with the line `public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;`. Also within the `Example` class I defined an `OnPropertyChanging` method to simplify raising the event. And then there is code inside the setter of the `ExampleValue` property to use that: `this.OnPropertyChanging("ExampleValue", _ExampleValue, value)`

Answer (score 2):

The accepted response is really bad, you can do that simply with Buffer().

```
Observable.FromEventPattern<PropertyChangedEventArgs>(Instance.Address, "PropertyChanged")
    .Where(e => e.EventArgs.PropertyName == "City")
    .Buffer(2,1)  //Take 2 events at a time, every 1 event
    .ObserveOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool)
    .Subscribe(search => ...); //search[0] is old value, search[1] is new value
```

Comment: Mmm...a couple of problems: 1) The built-in PropertyChanged/PropertyChanging events do not provide the new or original values of the property, which would be necessary for this "Buffer" approach to work. 2) This approach requires the event to fire more than once so that you can compare the property value as it changes between two events. The OP might want to be able to observe the previous and current values of the property for only a single event. 3) The OP wants to be able to cancel the change to the property value. The built-in PropertyChanging event does not provide a cancel mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that does want the best of both RX and being able to Cancel here is a hybrid of both of these ideas

The ViewModel base class stuff

```
public abstract class INPCBase : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
{
    public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected bool OnPropertyChanging<T>(string propertyName, T originalValue, T newValue)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanging;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            var args = new PropertyChangingCancelEventArgs<T>(propertyName, originalValue, newValue);
            handler(this, args);
            return !args.Cancel;
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged<T>(string propertyName, T previousValue, T currentValue)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs<T>(propertyName, previousValue, currentValue));
    }
}


public class PropertyChangingCancelEventArgs : PropertyChangingEventArgs
{
    public bool Cancel { get; set; }

    public PropertyChangingCancelEventArgs(string propertyName)
        : base(propertyName)
    {
    }
}

public class PropertyChangingCancelEventArgs<T> : PropertyChangingCancelEventArgs
{
    public T OriginalValue { get; private set; }

    public T NewValue { get; private set; }

    public PropertyChangingCancelEventArgs(string propertyName, T originalValue, T newValue)
        : base(propertyName)
    {
        this.OriginalValue = originalValue;
        this.NewValue = newValue;
    }
}

public class PropertyChangedEventArgs<T> : PropertyChangedEventArgs
{
    public T PreviousValue { get; private set; }

    public T CurrentValue { get; private set; }

    public PropertyChangedEventArgs(string propertyName, T previousValue, T currentValue)
        : base(propertyName)
    {
        this.PreviousValue = previousValue;
        this.CurrentValue = currentValue;
    }
}
```

Then I have these couple extensions.

One to get the property name from Expression tree

```
public static class ExpressionExtensions
{

    public static string GetPropertyName<TProperty>(this Expression<Func<TProperty>> expression)
    {
        var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (memberExpression == null)
        {
            var unaryExpression = expression.Body as UnaryExpression;
            if (unaryExpression != null)
            {
                if (unaryExpression.NodeType == ExpressionType.ArrayLength)
                    return "Length";
                memberExpression = unaryExpression.Operand as MemberExpression;

                if (memberExpression == null)
                {
                    var methodCallExpression = unaryExpression.Operand as MethodCallExpression;
                    if (methodCallExpression == null)
                        throw new NotImplementedException();

                    var arg = (ConstantExpression)methodCallExpression.Arguments[2];
                    return ((MethodInfo)arg.Value).Name;
                }
            }
            else
                throw new NotImplementedException();

        }

        var propertyName = memberExpression.Member.Name;
        return propertyName;

    }

    public static string GetPropertyName<T, TProperty>(this Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;

        if (memberExpression == null)
        {
            var unaryExpression = expression.Body as UnaryExpression;

            if (unaryExpression != null)
            {
                if (unaryExpression.NodeType == ExpressionType.ArrayLength)
                    return "Length";
                memberExpression = unaryExpression.Operand as MemberExpression;

                if (memberExpression == null)
                {
                    var methodCallExpression = unaryExpression.Operand as MethodCallExpression;
                    if (methodCallExpression == null)
                        throw new NotImplementedException();

                    var arg = (ConstantExpression)methodCallExpression.Arguments[2];
                    return ((MethodInfo)arg.Value).Name;
                }
            }
            else
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        var propertyName = memberExpression.Member.Name;
        return propertyName;

    }

    public static String PropertyToString<R>(this Expression<Func<R>> action)
    {
        MemberExpression ex = (MemberExpression)action.Body;
        return ex.Member.Name;
    }

    public static void CheckIsNotNull<R>(this Expression<Func<R>> action, string message)
    {
        MemberExpression ex = (MemberExpression)action.Body;
        string memberName = ex.Member.Name;
        if (action.Compile()() == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(memberName, message);
        }
    }

}
```

And then the Rx part

```
public static class ObservableExtensions
{

    public static IObservable<ItemPropertyChangingEvent<TItem, TProperty>> ObserveSpecificPropertyChanging<TItem, TProperty>(
        this TItem target, Expression<Func<TItem, TProperty>> propertyName) where TItem : INotifyPropertyChanging
    {
        var property = propertyName.GetPropertyName();

        return ObserveSpecificPropertyChanging(target, property)
               .Select(i => new ItemPropertyChangingEvent<TItem, TProperty>()
               {
                   OriginalEventArgs = (PropertyChangingCancelEventArgs<TProperty>)i.OriginalEventArgs,
                   Property = i.Property,
                   Sender = i.Sender
               });
    }

    public static IObservable<ItemPropertyChangingEvent<TItem>> ObserveSpecificPropertyChanging<TItem>(
        this TItem target, string propertyName = null) where TItem : INotifyPropertyChanging
    {

        return Observable.Create<ItemPropertyChangingEvent<TItem>>(obs =>
        {
            Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo> properties = new Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo>();
            PropertyChangingEventHandler handler = null;

            handler = (s, a) =>
            {
                if (propertyName == null || propertyName == a.PropertyName)
                {
                    PropertyInfo prop;
                    if (!properties.TryGetValue(a.PropertyName, out prop))
                    {
                        prop = target.GetType().GetProperty(a.PropertyName);
                        properties.Add(a.PropertyName, prop);
                    }
                    var change = new ItemPropertyChangingEvent<TItem>()
                    {
                        Sender = target,
                        Property = prop,
                        OriginalEventArgs = a,
                    };

                    obs.OnNext(change);
                }
            };

            target.PropertyChanging += handler;

            return () =>
            {
                target.PropertyChanging -= handler;
            };
        });
    }



    public class ItemPropertyChangingEvent<TSender>
    {
        public TSender Sender { get; set; }
        public PropertyInfo Property { get; set; }
        public PropertyChangingEventArgs OriginalEventArgs { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Sender: {0}, Property: {1}", Sender, Property);
        }
    }


    public class ItemPropertyChangingEvent<TSender, TProperty>
    {
        public TSender Sender { get; set; }
        public PropertyInfo Property { get; set; }
        public PropertyChangingCancelEventArgs<TProperty> OriginalEventArgs { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Then example usage will be like this

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INPCBase
{
    private string field1;
    private string field2;


    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        field1 = "Hello";
        field2 = "World";

        this.ObserveSpecificPropertyChanging(x => x.Field2)
           .Subscribe(x =>
           {
               if (x.OriginalEventArgs.NewValue == "DOG")
               {
                   x.OriginalEventArgs.Cancel = true;
               }
           });

    }

    public string Field1
    {
        get
        {
            return field1;
        }
        set
        {
            if (field1 != value)
            {
                if (this.OnPropertyChanging("Field1", field1, value))
                {
                    var previousValue = field1;
                    field1 = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("Field1", previousValue, value);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public string Field2
    {
        get
        {
            return field2;
        }
        set
        {
            if (field2 != value)
            {
                if (this.OnPropertyChanging("Field2", field2, value))
                {
                    var previousValue = field2;
                    field2 = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("Field2", previousValue, value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Works a treat