# (is there an) Easy way to check if property in (complex) pocomodel has changed?

Tags: c#

I was wondering if there is an 'easy'/good way to check if a property has changed. Like in the hierarchy below when Child.Name has changed (isDirty) I would like to know.

```
GrantParent
- Parent
-- Child
```

In my current situation I need to navigate through the model to see if anything has changed.

ps: I'm using `IChangeTracking`.

Been thinking about caching a hash of the serialized object. (too slow?)

Or creating changedevent which call's the parent until it reaches the grantparent. (chatty?)

```
  public class Parent: BaseEntity
  {
    private Child _child;
    public Child Child
    {
      get { return _child; }
      set { _child = value; OnPropertyChanged("Child"); }
    }
  }

  public class Child : BaseEntity
  {
    private  int _id;
    public int Id {
      get { return _id; }
      set { _id = value; OnPropertyChanged("Id"); }
    }
  }



 [DataContract]
  [Serializable]
  public abstract class BaseEntity : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    protected BaseEntity()
    {
      PropertyChanged += PropertyChangedEventHandler;
    }

    private void PropertyChangedEventHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e != null && !String.Equals(e.PropertyName, "IsChanged", StringComparison.Ordinal))
      {
        this.IsChanged = true;
      }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> property)
    {
      MemberExpression me = property.Body as MemberExpression;
      if (me == null || me.Expression != property.Parameters[0]
            || me.Member.MemberType != MemberTypes.Property)
      {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(
            "Now tell me about the property");
      }
      var handler = PropertyChanged;
      if (handler != null) handler(this,
        new PropertyChangedEventArgs(me.Member.Name));
    }

    [Browsable(false), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public bool IsChanged
    {
      get
      {
        lock (_notifyingObjectIsChangedSyncRoot)
        {
          return _notifyingObjectIsChanged;
        }
      }

      protected set
      {
        lock (_notifyingObjectIsChangedSyncRoot)
        {
          if (!Boolean.Equals(_notifyingObjectIsChanged, value))
          {
            _notifyingObjectIsChanged = value;

            if (IsDirtyChanged != null)
              IsDirtyChanged();

            this.OnPropertyChanged("IsChanged");
          }
        }
      }
    }

    private bool _notifyingObjectIsChanged;
    private readonly object _notifyingObjectIsChangedSyncRoot = new Object();

    public void AcceptChanges()
    {
      this.IsChanged = false;
    }
  }
```

**In the end** I used a compare on the XML model from the XML serializer I already used. I did't 'need' instant change detection once a second (or so) would be enough. Now I check the XML model with the one I had since the last save.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm not familiar with Transparent proxies. (will look it up though)

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580307/handling-propertychanging-propertychanged-via-castles-dynamicproxy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently worked on a project where we had all of the nodes/leaves implement a `node.Modified` property and used `INotifyPropertyChanged` to raise state change of `node.Modified`. Then all of the parents subscribed to their children's property change and if `node.Modified` was ever set true, then they'd set their own `node.Modified` to true.

Like you say, it's a little chatty, but hasn't come close to becoming a performance bottleneck for us since we're not seeing thousands of changes every second and our hierarchy is only 3 levels deep.

Here's a quick sample:

```
class Node : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public Node()
    {
        Children = new List<Node>();
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        var temp = PropertyChanged;
        if (temp != null)
            temp(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    public IList<Node> Children { get; private set; }
    public void AddChild(Node node)
    {
        node.PropertyChanged += ChildPropertyChanged;
        Children.Add(node);
    }

    void ChildPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.PropertyName == "Modified")
            Modified |= ((Node)sender).Modified;
    }

    bool _modified = false; 
    public bool Modified 
    {
        get { return _modified; } 
        set 
        {
            if (_modified != value)
            {
                _modified = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Modified");
            }

        } 
    }
```

EDIT: There is another way using a sort of message bus. It may not be perfect, but it is another approach to the problem, so I will share that as well. I quickly hacked up a trivial Msg bus...

```
static class Bus<T>
{

    public static Dictionary<object, Action<object, T>> Subscriptions = new Dictionary<object, Action<object, T>>();
    public static void Raise(object sender, T message)
    {
        foreach (Action<object, T> action in Subscriptions.Values)
        {
            action(sender, message);
        }
    }

    public static void Subscribe(object subscriber, Action<object, T> action)
    {
        Subscriptions[subscriber] = action;
    }

    public static void Unsubscribe(object subscriber)
    {
        if (Subscriptions.ContainsKey(subscriber))
            Subscriptions.Remove(subscriber);
    }

}

public class WasModified { }
```

And the modified Node

```
class Node
{

    public Node()
    {
        Children = new List<Node>();
    }

    public IList<Node> Children { get; private set; }

    bool _modified = false; 
    public bool Modified 
    {
        get { return _modified; } 
        set 
        {
            if (_modified != value)
            {
                _modified = value;

                if (_modified == true)
                    Bus<WasModified>.Raise(this, new WasModified());
            }

        } 
    }
}
```

Finally, it's use.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Node parent = new Node();
        Bus<WasModified>.Subscribe(parent, (s,a)=> parent.Modified = true);
        Node child = new Node();
        Node gchild = new Node();
        parent.Children.Add(child);
        parent.Children.Add(gchild);
        gchild.Modified = true;
        Console.WriteLine(parent.Modified);


        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

The message bus doesn't need to bubble up to parent objects and you don't need to recurse into them each time you want to see if Modified was changed, so perhaps it's what you're looking for.

Comment: Raising events is an obvious choice which will work (although bit chatty). The message bus has no reference to the rootnode (unless recursively adding these). So I can detect a change but not to which rootnode.

Comment: @rdkleine sure you do. It's the sender. In the example above in the Main function it's the s variable of `Bus<WasModified>.Subscribe(parent, (s,a)=> parent.Modified = true);`

Comment: Well to be more precise it's any subscriber. Although I like the idea I think its unsuitable for my project unless I can detect the context somehow. I'm working on a Visual Studio Designer which can have multiple designers open each working on there own 'Parent'. So I'll have to figure out a way to know which subnode belongs to which parent in the Raise method.

Comment: I see your point now, yes the children have no connection the root in this model. I assumed (incorrectly) the child would be enough information for your efforts.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to have each of the properties keep track of it themselves, and either store some information indicating what properties have changed, or possibly firing off an event when an item is changed.

essentially each property will have logic similar to this:

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _value;
    public int Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

This will allow you to add an event handler to the PropertyChanged event so that code will be fired when a property is changed.

Comment: I'm using IChackTracking to do this for me. I can call each object to ask if it has changed, only I don't want to asked but notified somehow.

Comment: I concur. As a simpler route, you could just add `isChanged` as a property of the object, but you would have to go out and check that each time.

Comment: @aserwin He says that's what he's currently doing, and he doesn't want to have to iterate the whole tree to find the changed items.

Comment: @Servy I didn't see that, my bad. Basically I was agreeing with you that firing an even is probably the most efficient way to handle it.

Comment: Added my own code to get more perspective. When I change Child I want the Parent to be dirty (that sounds awkward somehow..).

Comment: @rdkleine Just have each parent subscribe to the event handler of each of it's children, and fire it's own event in the event handler.

Comment: I was hoping I didn't have to go there.